# To define Labelfor attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How I can define `@Html.Labelfor` attribute for my below  mentioned code:

```
 <span class="gender-span">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Tagged, (int)TaggingType.All, new { @class = "radio-style", @name = "tag", @id = "track" })
                                        <label for="track">@Resources.Track</label>
```

I want to use @Html.Labelfor attribute. Now please assist me to fix this.

Comment: Do you want a label associated with the radio button? Note remove the `@name = "tag"` (fortunately it does absolutely nothing - and if it did your app would fail) and remove `@id = "Tagged"` (its just pointless since the helper already generates `id="Tagged"`

Comment: I have updated id attribute please check now.

Comment: You could use `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Tagged, new { for = "track" })` - although I suspect you might really want `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Tagged, "All", new { for = "track" })` so its displays "All". But for radio buttons its generally easier to just wrap button in a `<label>` tag. And you still need to remove the `@name="tag"` :)

Comment: This solution is not working. Stephen, I have updated my issue once again. Can you please check if you can assist me. Thank you.

Comment: What you have shown will work fine. What is not working for you? I assume you have other radio buttons (a single radio button is useless). Are you giving then different `id` attributes?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple radio buttons with different id attributes. My code is showing issue due to re-sharper warning 'Cannot resolve Id' so I want to use @Html.Labelfor.